# What permissions are needed to truncate a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, truncate

I’ve just started with a web host which supports PostgreSQL.

When setting up a database user, I have the choice of the following privileges:

■ ALTER ■ CREATE ■ DELETE
■ EXECUTE ■ DROP ■ EVENT
■ INDEX ■ INSERT SELECT
■ TRIGGER ■ UPDATE

That doesn’t include `TRUNCATE`, though it does include more drastic privileges. I plan to include the `DELETE`,`EXECUTE`,`INSERT`,`SELECT`,`UPDATE` privileges, but what’s needed to permit `TRUNCATE` without giving too much away?

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the `TRUNCATE` privilege to truncate a table (or be a superuser).

Since PostgreSQL has no `INDEX`, `EVENT`, `ALTER` or `DROP` privileges, I suspect that you are using a different software.

Comment: I think you’re right. The DBMS is definitely PostgreSQL, as I can connect to it and the code runs properly. However their web interface to the user info appears to be incorrect, presumably set for MySQL. I have lodged a support request with them, and they acknowledge that it’s wrong. I’ll get back.

Comment: @Manngo could you include the name of the interface in the tags/question? Also if the support request is public (e.g. git-issue) it be also worth including.